# What is the term to describe "Transitivity" in network security?

Tags: network, social-engineering, terminology

> If A's security is breached, while A and B are in the same network,
>   then B's security is breached.

I can imagine this could happen to computer networks, but also to social networks; for example if Bob maliciously accesses the Facebook account of Alice, Bob could then unveil private information about third parties that trusted Alice with private information (e.g. through private personal messages, privacy settings, etc..).

Is there a term that describes this form of "transitivity" in networks?

Comment: Mohammed - I don't see this being a security question. Can you say why you can't use the phrase you already have, or security, or trust etc...?

Comment: Transitivity is a core math concept for relations. Your question involves sets (networks), and subsets (set of hosts in the network), different concepts. What you describe here is unrelated to any kind of transitivity.

Answer (score 0):

This is more about a domino effect or **contagion**.

The leve of security in a network is considered to be the same as the **weakest link** of the network.